# Pass url params to Strapi endpoint

Tags: reactjs, strapi, react-hook-form, react-query

I'm working on a real estate application where you can search properties by either it's type or location or a combination of both. I'm using React query and React-hook-form to submit the form but I don't know how to pass the value of the type and location as a url parameter. Should it be a useQuery or useMutation? I would appreciate any help...Thanks.

```js
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "react-query";
import { makeRequest } from "../config";

// Function to get all types and locations and populate their respective inputs 
export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery(["data", url], async () => {
    const res = await makeRequest.get(url);
    return res.data.data;
  });

  return { data, isLoading, error };
};

//Function to get properties by type or location or both
export const useGetProperties = (url: string) => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useMutation(["data", url], async () => {
    const res = await makeRequest.post(url);
    return res.data.data;
  });

  return { data, isLoading, error };
};
```

```js
import { Flex, Select } from 
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useFetch, useGetProperties } from "../../hooks/fetchData";

export const Form = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

  const { data: locations } = useFetch("/locations");
  const { data: types } = useFetch("/types");

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
  //Does this make any sense?
  
    {/*const { data: properties } = useGetProperties("/properties?filters[type]"); */}
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <Flex gap={3}>
         <Select
           {...register("location")}
           name="location"
          >
             {locations?.map((item: any) => (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.attributes.name}>
                  {item.attributes.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Select>

            <Select
              {...register("type")}
              fontSize={{ sm: "12px", lg: "lg" }}
              placeholder="Property type"
              name="type"
              height="50px"
              borderColor="gray"
            >
              {types?.map((item: any) => (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.attributes.name}>
                  {item.attributes.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Flex>

          <Button
            type="submit"
          >
            Search
          </Button>
      </form>
  );
};
```